# Check presence of object property during bulding phase

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, eslint

I am looking for a solution that helps me achieve this:

I would like to have at 'build' time an error throwed if I try doing this:

```
var ciao = {
  wow: 'ciaoooo',
}

console.log(ciao.wowe); // this should be an error because the prop does not exist
```

I have tried Typescript and it does the jobs, but it seems an overkill use it only for this. I was wondering if there was something for ESLint or something else that can help me with this type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for features of a statically typed language. If you want reliable information about variables on build time, you'll need this *"overkill"* of defining interfaces and types. TypeScript, however, is optionally typed, which might be a good compromise if you want static types for your public interfaces.

If you want type checking but don't want to use a transpiler, you could also try [Flow](http://flowtype.org/) which tries to derive type information just from your code as much as possible. However, its capabilities without additional type information are very limited.

**Concerning your actual question:** I think it would be possible to derive type information within module (or file) boundaries with ESLint or Babel. As long as you are using that object just within these boundaries, static analysis can probably help you. But beyond that, I don't think it's reliably feasible because of the dynamic nature of JavaScript. Unfortunately, I don't know such a rule or plugin.

Answer (score 1):

ESLint doesn't have a rule like that. It would be very hard to create a rule that would be able to catch all possible cases for this. ESLint relies on Escope to track declared variables, but Escope doesn't track object properties, and there are just too many ways to add a property to a declared object.